# EIP-712 Signing Messages fails

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I have a modified truffle react box contract that should have EIP712 standard:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <8.10.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    string public constant name = "SimpleStorage";

    bytes32 public immutable DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
    bytes32 public constant MESSAGE_HASH =
        keccak256("Data(address sender, uint value)");

    uint256 storedData;

    constructor() {
        uint256 chainId;
        assembly {
            chainId := chainid()
        }
        DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256(
                    "EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId)"
                ),
                keccak256(bytes(name)),
                keccak256(bytes("1")),
                chainId
            )
        );
    }

    function setPermit(
        address sender,
        uint256 value,
        bytes memory sig
    ) external {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "\x19\x01",
                DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
                keccak256(abi.encode(MESSAGE_HASH, sender, value))
            )
        );

        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;

        assembly {
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(recoveredAddress == sender, "INVALID_SIGNATURE");
        storedData = value;
    }

    function permit(
        address sender,
        uint256 value,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) external {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "\x19\x01",
                DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
                keccak256(abi.encode(MESSAGE_HASH, sender, value))
            )
        );

        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(
            recoveredAddress != address(0) && recoveredAddress == sender,
            "INVALID_SIGNATURE"
        );
        storedData = value;
    }

    function set(uint256 x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint256) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Code, that creates hash structures and calls contract functions:

```
 signMessage = async () => {
    const { web3, accounts, contract, address } = this.state;
    var signer = accounts[0];
    var value = 50; 
    const chainId = await web3.eth.getChainId();

    const domain = [
      { name: "name", type: "string" },
      { name: "version", type: "string" },
      { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
    ]; 
    const data = [
      { name: "sender", type: "address" },
      { name: "value", type: "uint" },
    ];

    const domainData = {
      name: "SimpleStorage",
      version: "1",
      chainId: chainId,
    }; 

    const messageData = {
      sender: signer,
      value: value,
    }; 

    const msgParams = JSON.stringify({
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: domain,
        Data: data,
      },
      domain: domainData,
      primaryType: "Data",
      message: messageData,
    });
    console.log(msgParams); 

    web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
      method: "eth_signTypedData_v4", 
      params: [signer, msgParams], 
      from: signer
    }, async function(err, result) {
      if(err) { return console.error(err); }
      const signResult = result.result;
    
      await contract.methods.setPermit(signer, value, signResult)
      .send({ from: signer });
      const response = await contract.methods.get().call();
      this.setState({ storageValue: response });
    }); 
  };
```

I've deployed the contract to the Rinkeby (0x729352f7541F205226234e3B8C4ABB820c68B380), but each time I'm trying to use setPermit function I'm receiving "This transaction is expected to fail" error in Metamask. Further investigation showed that transaction [fails](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xe55f9a930209d778bc245a05a4aeda41f9611f6164d20fdf14df9368dc5b55ba). How do I fix this?